# How to get to an element on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want to access the an element and using:

```
$('#classname').scroll(function(){
    // code here  
    alert("here");


});

$('#classname').ready(function(){
    // code here  
    alert("here");


});
```

The problem I face is this, that the ready function is called but not the scroll and after going through jquery's api, I got to know this:

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with theoverflow CSS property set to
>   scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height is less than the
>   height of its contents).

Thus, when a page loads, I am able to get the divs. But when I scroll down for the rest of the page to load, the `.ready` or the `.scroll` events are not fired. How do I manage to get that?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to trigger an action when the element comes in to view?

Comment: If _classname_ is a class name, it should be `.classname` and also ready event is fired by document object not by the elements on the page.

Comment: @undefined The ready method can be called with any target: the target is irrelevant and it is executed when the DOM is ready regardless

Comment: I think you are looking for `.offset()` to get the element's relative position to the document and then animate using scrollTop

Comment: @nbrooks Yes, that's true, the point was clarification.

Comment: code vs text...apears to be misunderstanding of what `scroll()` method does... start by reviewing API docs. A demo would also help in jsfiddle.net

Comment: My bad. Yes, it is a .classname. What I am trying to do is inject certain text wherever the div is. The problem is I get the access to the div, when the window loads(on ready) but nothing when it scrolls.

Comment: I think he wants to capture the scroll event itself and act on it, not animate scrolling in the document. If I understood, correctly, see answer below, otherwise please clarify :)

Comment: Yes, sir. You did understand it correctly and your answer isn't working, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to capture the scroll event and fire a behavior when the view is scrolled? You want something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".classname").on("scroll", function(event) {
        console.log($(event));
    });
});
```

And you need to make sure `.classname` is scrollable - for example, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .classname {
        height:600px;
        width:800px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .inner {
        height:1500px;
        width:800px;
        border:solid black 1px;
    }
</style>
<div class="classname">
    <div class="inner">
       text<br>
       text<br>
       text<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. Is there any change in behavior at all? Tested and it is working for me. Oh, I also set style for body dimensions - `body { height:300px;width:1000px; }` . Try $(".classname").trigger("scroll"); in the console - what happens?

Comment: I tried both ready and scroll and neither work for (document).ready. Though classname.ready() works for (Window).ready

Comment: Okay, that's kind of weird - or did you mean something like `$(Window).ready(function() { $(".classname").scroll(function() { console.log("whatever"); }); });`

Comment: Also, did you run `$(".classname").trigger("scroll");` in the console? Did anything happen?

Comment: The thing is I can always write it window.scroll() but that makes loading of the web page terribly slow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21606/discussion-between-leah-l-and-puck)

Comment: Ok, OP advices - this is a Chrome extension, fwiw; I used the jquery snippet from the above example and only changed the targeting. Otherwise, identical code is working for me in Chrome console w/ tweetdeck. The thing is, you have to make sure you're targeting exactly the element that's scrolling when it's not the window itself (hence your super slow working case.) If you're using scroller, or datatables, doesn't matter - but, the element needs to be scrollable (give it dimensions) and make sure the element itself can actually scroll (overflow, w/e.) Script that in as well, if necessary.